# Can't Activate Document in Pipeline (unix script)

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to run the program [bayes-seg](https://github.com/jacobeisenstein/bayes-seg) with: `cat data/books/clinical/050.ref | ./segment config/dp.config` using Powershell.

I understand that the command `cat` outputs the file and `pipe` will use the output as a parameter to `./segment config/dp.config`

When running the above command. I'm met with the exception:

```
Cannot run a document in the middle of a pipeline: C:\Users\name\Desktop\bayes-seg-master\segment.
At line:1 char:35
+ cat data/books/clinical/050.ref | ./segment config/dp.config
+ CategoryInfo: InvalidOperation: (C:\Users\name\...-master\segment:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CantActivateDocumentInPipeline
```

What causes this exception? I've looked around on Google and could not find anything which explains the exception in detail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Comment: No, it was one of many final straws which pushed me to linux. Have not looked back since.

Comment: Strange.  Other external commands work ok:  `cat file1 | findstr 1`, assuming segment.exe takes pipeline input.

Comment: That site says segment is a unix script.  It would not run in windows.

Comment: Since this is a unix script that wouldn't run in windows, I would close this.

Answer (score 0):

As the executable `segment.exe` is not aware of PowerShell style pipeline, you must use `ForEach-Object` to specify a specific argument to `segment.exe`:

```
cat data/books/clinical/050.ref | %{ ./segment config/dp.config $_ }
```

As I'm not aware of this executable usage, you may need to adapt the arguments as you need.